# jQuery show/hide focus issues

Tags: jquery, focus

Have a dropdown appearing from below input text field. Currently configured to hide this dropdown if the text input field goes out of focus. Problem is, the user needs to be able to click on the dropdown itself to show another area, but in doing this the dropdown itself hides before the other area displays. Comment-out [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hotdiggity/uPgu6/) lines 15-17 to see correct display of other area.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <title>Dynamic show/hide</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(function () {

              $(".addressFill").hide();
              $(".dropdown").hide();

              function showElem() {
                  $(".addressFill").show();
              }

              $(".addresspicker").click(function () {
                  $("ul.dropdown").toggle();
              });

              // Problem starts here
              $(".addresspicker").focusout(function () {
                  $(".dropdown").hide();
              });
              // ends

              $("ul.dropdown").on("click", "li", showElem);
          });
        </script>
        <style>
        .dropdown { margin-left: 0.5em; padding: 0.5em; background: #fff; position: absolute; z-index: 999; border-top: 1px solid #B9B9B9; border-left: 1px solid #B9B9B9; border-right: 1px solid #7D7D7D; border-bottom: 1px solid #7D7D7D; }
        ul { list-style-type: none; }
        .dropdown li { padding: 0.5em; }
        .dropdown li:hover { background-color: #eee; }
        .dropdown li a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
        p.addressFill { float: right; }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
    <form>
<fieldset>
        <div class="section">
          <label class="FieldLabel">Address:<span class="required">*</span></label>
          <div class="autofill">
        <input name="" maxlength="38" size="38" id="" type="text" title="addresspicker" class="addresspicker" />
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
        <p class="addressFill"> Show/hide section </p>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better way but you could try and utilize [**setTimeout()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) with a delay to automatically close the menu when the user is done with it and/or after a given time has passed, similar to this:

```
// stores the setTimeout result
var timeOut;

// closes the menu
var closeMenu = function () {
    $("ul.dropdown").hide();
};

// resets the timeout using the specified delay
var resetTimeout = function(newDelay){
    if (timeOut > 0) {
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }

        timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
            closeMenu()
        }, newDelay);
};

$(function () {
    // use to store timeout
    var timeOut = null;

    // ...removed unchanged code for readability

    // Problem starts here

    // reset timeout when focus is lost on input
    $(".addresspicker").focusout(function () {
        resetTimeout(1000);
    });

    // reset the timeout when moving over or leaving the menu
    $("ul.dropdown").on('mousemove mouseleave', function () {
        resetTimeout(1000);
    })
    // ends

    // ...removed unchanged code for readability
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/N5ER8/) - Using `setTimeout()`

---

This is just one of the many variations of using `setTimeout()`. You can get quite elaborate to improve user experience.
There might well be a more efficient way of doing it all together as well off course.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [.stopPropagation();](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/uPgu6/10/) - Basically clicking in the document will hide the dropdown, unless you are clicking `.addresspicker`or `.dropdown`.

```
// Removed the focusout and added these...
$(".addresspicker, .dropdown").click(function ( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function( e ){
    $("ul.dropdown").hide();
});
```

Comment: +1 as this is a working solution. Just to keep in mind though that when using `.stopPropagation();`, that any click event bound to a parent of `.addresspicker` or `.dropdown` will now not be triggered anymore when those elements are clicked. Though in this specific scenario I doubt this will be causing any issues, unless `div.autofill`, `div.section` or the `form` will have a click event assigned at some stage.